# Верстка слайдера на css

Tags: css, css3, html5

Нужно сверстать такой вот слайдер. Проблема возникает при верстке левой и правой кнопки, просто не хватает понятия что с ними делать. И еще есть проблема с переполнением. Как спозиционировать навигацию так, чтобы положение чекбоксов зависило от наполнения контентом внутри слайдера. Как с этим всем бороться? Сверстать нужно без флексов и четко по заданному HTML. Вот что получилось у меня  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.reviews {
  position: relative;
  width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 37px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: #f8f5f2;
}

.reviews__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  min-height: 255px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.reviews__title {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 160px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #e5ddd5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__input {
  display: none;
}

.reviews__item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 540px;
  min-height: 160px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding-top: 33.5px;
  padding-left: 140px;
  padding-bottom: 34.5px;
  border: 1px solid #e5ddd5;
}

.reviews__author-foto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 30px;
}

.reviews__author-foto img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.reviews__author-name {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.reviews__list p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 13px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reviews__list {
  width: 300%;
}

.reviews__list button {
  display: none;
}

.slider__toggles {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 257px;
  bottom: 47px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f8f5f2;
}

.slider__toggles label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-right: 23px;
  font-size: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid #929292;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#reviews-input-1:checked~.slider__toggles label[for="reviews-input-1"],
#reviews-input-2:checked~.slider__toggles label[for="reviews-input-2"],
#reviews-input-3:checked~.slider__toggles label[for="reviews-input-3"] {
  background-color: #353535;
}

#reviews-input-1:checked~.reviews__list {
  transform: translate(0);
}

#reviews-input-2:checked~.reviews__list {
  transform: translate(-640px);
}

#reviews-input-3:checked~.reviews__list {
  transform: translate(-1280px);
}
```

```html
<section class="reviews">
  <div class="reviews__wrapper slider">
    <h2 class="reviews__title">Отзывы о нас</h2>
    <a href="" class="reviews__write btn">Оставить свой</a>

    <input type="radio" class="slider__input" name="reviews" id="reviews-input-1" checked>
    <input type="radio" class="slider__input" name="reviews" id="reviews-input-2">
    <input type="radio" class="slider__input" name="reviews" id="reviews-input-3">

    <div class="reviews__list clearfix">
      <blockquote class="reviews__item slider__item">
        <div class="reviews__author-foto">
          <img src="img/travis.jpg" width="50" height="48" alt="Фото Трэвисиа Баркера">
        </div>
        <cite class="reviews__author-name">Трэвис Баркер</cite>
        <p>Спасибо за лысину! Был проездом в Москве, заскочил побриться, чтобы было видно новую татуировку!</p>
      </blockquote>
      <blockquote class="reviews__item slider__item">
        <div class="reviews__author-foto">
          <img src="img/travis.jpg" width="50" height="48" alt="Фото Трэвисиа Баркера">
        </div>
        <cite class="reviews__author-name">Джон Смит</cite>
        <p>Отличную стрижку мне сделали ребята.</p>
      </blockquote>
      <blockquote class="reviews__item slider__item">
        <div class="reviews__author-foto">
          <img src="img/travis.jpg" width="50" height="48" alt="Фото Трэвисиа Баркера">
        </div>
        <cite class="reviews__author-name">Иван Бородайло</cite>
        <p>В Бородинском ваша борода в надёжных руках</p>
      </blockquote>

      <button class="reviews__prev" type="button">Предыдущий отзыв</button>
      <button class="reviews__next" type="button">Следующий отзыв</button>
    </div>

    <div class="reviews__toggles slider__toggles">
      <label for="reviews-input-1" class="slider__toggle" checked>1</label>
      <label for="reviews-input-2" class="slider__toggle">2</label>
      <label for="reviews-input-3" class="slider__toggle">3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Это адаптивный барбершоп?

Comment: Если да, откройте гитхаб, вбейте в поиск "барбершоп" и пошарьте по репозиториям. Чтобы не качать все подряд, открывайте файл css прямо на гитхабе и ищите медиа-запросы. Если их нет, значит верстка с базового интенсива (не адаптивная, там нет такого слайдера).

Comment: хорошая идея, спасибо)